# Why was my answer not migrated with a question?

Tags: support

Recently, a question was migrated from SO to CV.se:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28719/two-way-anova-on-data-with-neither-normality-nor-equality-of-variance-in-r

However, my answer was not migrated along with the question. Is there a reason why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the existing answers were deleted manually before the question was migrated, so consequently they weren't moved with the question.

Comment: I did not delete my own answer - do you know how I can recover it?

Comment: @David It was deleted along with the other answer by the moderator casperOne, before he migrated the question. Any 10k+ user on Stack Overflow can recover its contents, [here's a copy for you](https://raw.github.com/gist/599fa85f204f2f0d032c/04537046626800a81dedf49524eb81188e545eb5/gistfile1.txt). There's no way to migrate the actual post itself over to CV now; you would need to repost.

Comment: @JeremyBanks thanks for the link. is deleting existing answers common practice?

Comment: @David - it's possible the answers were flagged by somebody separately before the migration

Comment: @David It's not a common practice. I'm not really sure why he removed the answers before migrating the question.

Comment: @AnnaLear Because it bordered on being a comment, and as a courtesy to the destination site, we clean up borderline comments before shipping over.  If the user does not have an account on the destination site then the answer will not have an owner.  If it's truly not an answer, but worthy of being a comment, it can't be converted to a comment by the moderators on that end and then the moderator is left with the unenviable decision of whether or not to delete the answer, which could have useful info, or keep something that's not an answer on their site.